# Define type from class Generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a class that you can pass a Generic to. That Generic is ought to be an object with keys and values. In that class I often refer to these keys and values:

```
class Service<C extends Converters> {
  public read<N extends keyof C>(name: N): C[N];
}
```

basically, `read` can receive a key in `Converters` as Generic and returns the corresponding value in converters.

I use that pattern about 10x in that class. Is there a way I can define the types *once* and reuse them? Something like

```
class Service<
  C extends Converters,
  Keys = keyof C,
  Values<K extends Keys> = C[K]
> {
  public read<Name extends Keys>(name: Name):Values<Name>;
}
```

But that ^ does not work

Comment: The first example is invalid.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet which actually compiles by itself, it'll make discussion much easier.

Comment: Sorry that was a copy & paste error, I fixed it

Comment: Wouldn't `class Service<C extends Converters, N extends keyof C> {
  public read(name: N): C[N] {` suit you?

Comment: If I have multiple methods using N, can they have different values? Because N seems to be defined as a single type across the entire class

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I use that pattern about 10x in that class"?  You mean that you have multiple methods with the same signature?  Or what?  Maybe give an example with at least 2x or 3x repetition so we can see what would make it work better.  And try to make this a [mcve] with no external dependencies... the only issue we should see in our IDE is the one you have; not things like "`Cannot find name 'Converters'.`" or "`Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.`".  Good luck!